# ORA-00600 When running ALTER command?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, ddl

I am running this command on a table :

`ALTER TABLE testTable ADD column1 NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;`

And i keep getting this error:
`Error report:

SQL Error: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kkpoffoc], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

00600. 00000 -  "internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]"

*Cause:    This is the generic internal error number for Oracle program

           exceptions.  This indicates that a process has encountered an
           exceptional condition.

*Action:   Report as a bug - the first argument is the internal error number`

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug, and you need to talk with your dba to make a SR as paxdiablo said.

If you are pressed for time, you can manually do what does

```
ALTER TABLE testTable ADD column1 NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
```

1. Add the column as null:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE testTable ADD column1 NUMBER(1);
   ```
2. Update values:

   ```
   update testTable set column1 = 0;
   ```
3. Alter table not null(between precedent and this, you must be sure that nobody inserts in the table):

   ```
   ALTER TABLE testTable MODIFY(column1  NOT NULL)
   ```

Comment: I just wanted to post this down. This is the answer I came up doing few seconds ago.

Answer (score 2):

Well, despite the fact you stated in your other question that you removed the `after` clause, it's still there :-)

But that's irrelevant. This is a serious bug with Oracle.

You need to report it to them (raise an SR with your Oracle Support rep), as the error message advises.