# Oracle 11g XE "alter table drop column" causes ORA-00600

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

On Oracle 11g XE I ran the following statement:

```
alter table le_customer drop column profile_id;
```

and then removed the equivalent column reference from a simple view on the table and recompiled the view successfully.

I then ran some PL/SQL that referenced the view and I started getting getting

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kkdcsaccc2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

(however if I changed the PL/SQL to reference the table directly then the code worked)

I have dropped and recreated the view and also run "alter table le_customer move ..." successfully, however the error continues to occur with 100% consistency.

I have shut the database down and run dbv against the database .dbf files - no errors were  reported.

I am running on a VM so I rolled the code back and removed the profile_id column reference from the view without physically removing the column from the le_customer table  ...and everything then worked fine with my code. Then I ran alter table le_customer drop column profile_id; again and immediately the ORA-00600 re-occurred.

I rolled the VM back again then ran

```
alter table le_customer rename column profile_id to donald_duck;
```

.......then tested and everything worked fine.

I then ran

```
alter table le_customer drop column donald_duck;
```

...then tested again and got the `ORA-00600` immediately.

So I am very sure that the problem is being caused by the "alter table le_customer drop column ;" statement and i am lost as to how to resolve it.

So, if anyone has seen this or has any ideas regarding a test / workaround I would greatly appreciate any info you are able to share - thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923091/ora-00600-when-running-alter-command

Comment: @Andrew - thanks, I have seen that question however there is a major difference in that it is possible to work around that problem whereas I cannot see how one can get around a failing "alter table x drop column y" statement. Also ORA-00600 is a broad spectrum error and the key 'kkpoffoc' in the other question is different from mine, which is'kkdcsaccc2'

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  You need to open a ticket with Oracle.

Comment: ORA-0600 errors are internal oracle errors.  My doc set says to contact oracle for 600 series errors.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: I don't think you can open tickets related to Oracle **XE**

Comment: A quick search on Metalink for `kkdcsaccc2` turned up 3 results for database versions <= 11gR1 (none of them seems relevant to your error). If possible, you should open a ticket with Oracle support (but I fear @a_horse_with_no_name is right - AFAIK it's not possible for XE). Otherwise, if you're running XE based on 11gR1, you might want to try the latest XE version, which is based on 11gR2.

Comment: @Frank Schmitt - Thanks so much for your input and for checking for the error. I am running the following version "Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production" so unfortunately it looks like the bug exists in 11gR2 also. Given that I have been dropping columns on tables in this schema for some years now without a single problem, this issue has really hit me like a hammer. Interestingly, I can mimic the error exactly on a colleagues VM running the same XE and schema structure so it is not restricted to my DB. My next step is to try to drop and recreate the table

Comment: Some good? news. I have executed the alter table drop command against an entirely different build of the database running the exact same schema and the error does NOT occur. As my colleague's database was cloned originally from the same database build, my current assessment is that this is very like a data dictionary corruption of some kind on this specific database build. We will continue our testing on this - thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: In conclusion: 1. Used datapump to export schema contents and data (pre "alter table drop column" statement being run) 2. Built a new empty database  3. imported the exported schema into the new database. 4. On the new database I ran the alter le_customer drop column profile_id statement 5. Selected from the view ....and all worked perfectly.  So in conclusion, I remain of the opinion that this problem was caused by a dictionary issue of some kind.

Answer (score 4):

My previous conclusion was incorrect ...as I have again seen the exact same problem, this time on 2 completely separate database builds. The problem table however remained the same one as before (ie. le_customer) and:

1. the schemas were identical on both databases
2. the identical query behaviour was consistent on both database
3. the query behaviour was consistent regardless of whether the simple
   view or base table was queried
4. The query consistently succeeded when no where clause was present
5. the query consistently failed as soon as as a simple where clause
   was    added ie. "where id = 123"
6. failure occurred regardless of the where clause content ie. "where
   code = 'ABC'" also failed
7. the "where clause" continued to cause query failure even after all indexes were
   dropped from the table

...I began dropping constraints one by one from the table, rerunning the query each time

And on removing the following constraint, the query started working!

```
constraint le_cus_bus_case_chk check(allow_case_boo = 'F'
                                     or
                                     case_master_template is not null
                                    )
```

A fairly innocuous constraint on the following 2 columns, where noticeably case_master_template is an xmltype stored "out of row"

```
 ...
 allow_case_boo varchar2(1) 
 case_master_template        xmltype
 ...
)
xmltype column case_master_template store as clob (disable storage in row)
```

To confirm this constraint to be the problem, on the other database deployment where the same behaviour was manifesting - and all indexes and constraints still existed on the table - , I dropped the above constraint only.  Immediately the problem disappeared and the query started working reliably.

I then removed all constraints, indexes, foreign keys from the table other than this one, and the query continued to manifest the ORA-00600 reliably. On removing this constraint last, the ORA-00600 disappeared from both view and table query (regardless of where clause existence).

So while i have no visibility of the internal workings, I do believe that I have identified the culprit, and can fairly confidently provide the recommendation to others to first check constraints on xmltype type columns that may exist should ORA-00600 "kkdcsaccc2" appear. And I will be removing the constraint from the table.

I hope this proves useful to someone.